# Hide Matdatepucker icon button based on date bselection from date picker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Matdatepickertoggle icon once click on the icon one datepicker picker will open and after date selection toogle icon button should be hide .
And with that date i have to show another Matdatepicker icon.

Please hep me on that..TIA

```
<mat-radio-button value="1">Daily Consumption</mat-radio-button>
    <inpu matInput class="date-input" [matDatepicker]="picker1"  readonly='true' required />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1">
      <mat-label matDatepickerToggleIcon>Select Date</mat-label>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
```

inside image you can see clearly that select date will hide and with selected date we have to add update date button same way .

Comment: Can you please share sample code and/or screen shots?

Comment: This is my first question how do i give the screen shot